# Can't find local git repositories

Tags: git, bash, github, repository, ls

Okay, so when I initialize a local repository using git init, I *know* that I created a repository.   Because, I use the following command  in git bash to find the repository that I just created:

```
find ~ -type d –name .git
```

And it finds the  repository exactly as I thought.  However, then when I go and try to navigate to that folder in using the change directory commands in git bash, none of the .git folders are showing up.

I give the command  `ls` to show the contents,  and  none of my  repositories show up.

Why is this?  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your `.git` directory is hidden. To list all the files or directories including hidden ones, you need to run `ls -a` command.